# Looping through data structures and comparing values vb.net

Tags: loops, data-structures, compare, vb.net-2010

this is very important.

The situation:
I am building a "game" with registering facility. I am using data structures and arrays. I have everything I need already, but the login. I need a loop that will:

- loop through an array/record
- compare what's in the array/record to what a user has entered into textboxes
- run other code

These are my storage methods:

```
Public Structure typRegistrationDetails
    Dim strUsername As String
    Dim strPassword As String
End Structure

Public Shared strUsers(0 To 2) As typRegistrationDetails
```

Number of users is for now limited to 3; each strUsers contains strUsername and strPassword.

I have already written code to register, tell me if you need to see it.

So now, I need a loop that will loop through the above structures and compare their values with what a user has entered.

I mean if txtUsername.Text (user input) and txtPassword.Text (user input) match one of strUsers(index) then do something, else do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Dim found As Boolean = False
For Each u As typRegistrationDetails In strUsers
    If u.strUserName = strUserName AndAlso
       u.strPassword = strPassword Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If found Then
    ' do something
Else
    ' do something else
End If
```